# YII login remember me error CWebUser.allowAutoLogin must be set true in order to use cookie-based authentication

Tags: php, yii

I am developing a Yii based system and the login works perfectly fine unless u tick  the remember me checkbox which shows the CWebUser.allowAutoLogin must be set true in order to use cookie-based authentication.

this is my LoginForm.php

```
<?php
 * LoginForm class.
* LoginForm is the data structure for keeping
* user login form data. It is used by the 'login' action of 'SiteController'.
*/
class LoginForm extends CFormModel
{
public $username;
public $password;
public $rememberMe;

private $_identity;

/**
 * Declares the validation rules.
 * The rules state that username and password are required,
 * and password needs to be authenticated.
 */
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        // username and password are required
        array('username, password', 'required'),
        // rememberMe needs to be a boolean
        array('rememberMe', 'boolean'),
        // password needs to be authenticated
        array('password', 'authenticate'),
    );
}

/**
 * Declares attribute labels.
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'rememberMe'=>'Remember me next time',
    );
}

/**
 * Authenticates the password.
 * This is the 'authenticate' validator as declared in rules().
 */
public function authenticate($attribute,$params)
{
    if(!$this->hasErrors())
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
        if(!$this->_identity->authenticate())
            $this->addError('password','Incorrect username or password.');
    }
}

/**
 * Logs in the user using the given username and password in the model.
 * @return boolean whether login is successful
 */
public function login()
{
    if($this->_identity===null)
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
        $this->_identity->authenticate();
    }
    if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
    {
        $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
        Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
}
```

and this is my  Controller

```
<?php

class SiteController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Declares class-based actions.
 */
public function actions()
{
    return array(
        // captcha action renders the CAPTCHA image displayed on the 
contact page
        'captcha'=>array(
            'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
            'backColor'=>0xFFFFFF,
        ),
        // page action renders "static" pages stored under   
'protected/views/site/pages'
        // They can be accessed via: index.php?r=site/page&view=FileName
        'page'=>array(
            'class'=>'CViewAction',
        ),
    );
}

/**
 * This is the default 'index' action that is invoked
 * when an action is not explicitly requested by users.
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
    // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
    $this->render('index');
}

        public function actionAdmin()
{
    // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
    // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
    $this->render('admin');
}
/**
 * This is the action to handle external exceptions.
 */
public function actionError()
{
    if($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
            echo $error['message'];
        else
            $this->render('error', $error);
    }
}

/**
 * Displays the contact page
 */
public function actionContact()
{
    $model=new ContactForm;
    if(isset($_POST['ContactForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['ContactForm'];
        if($model->validate())
        {
            $name='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($model->name).'?=';
            $subject='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($model->subject).'?=';
            $headers="From: $name <{$model->email}>\r\n".
                "Reply-To: {$model->email}\r\n".
                "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
                "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8";

            mail(Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'],$subject,$model-
 >body,$headers);
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('contact','Thank you for 
contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
            $this->refresh();
        }
    }
    $this->render('contact',array('model'=>$model));
}

/**
 * Displays the login page
 */
public function actionLogin()
{
    $model=new LoginForm;

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if($model->validate() && $model->login())

                    $this->redirect(array('site/index'));
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
}

/**
 * Logs out the current user and redirect to homepage.
 */
public function actionLogout()
{
    Yii::app()->user->logout();
    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->homeUrl);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Config main.php u set user allowAutoLogin true as shown below

```
'components'=>array(
        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        ),
```

Comment: thanks you so much!! Im new with Yii so things gets really confusing! I just learned to use it for a week >_< really thanks :D